# Broken dependencies issue is faced immediately after the first install of Ubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, g++

I followed these steps just to get rid of broken dependencies issue but to no avail.

1. A fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
2. Tried to install g++ by sudo apt-get install g++
3. BOOM... Broken Dependencies as before the new install

I thought, maybe I badly messed up things on my ubuntu VM so creating a fresh VM will not hurt and I will get everything neat and clean but no way. Is there something seriously wrong? Here is the error while installing g++

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
g++:i386 : Depends: cpp:i386 (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be      installed
        Depends: gcc:i386 (>= 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: g++-4.8:i386 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: gcc-4.8:i386 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit install of ubuntu?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you installed a new system, you need to update package lists by running

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Do it and try to install g++ again.

Comment: That's it !!! It worked. A fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.3 + sudo apt-get update solved it for me. Nevertheless, without reinstallation, I couldn't solve this same issue while installing g++. Thanks.